# Visual Studios Issue where only first section is being displayed

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am having some troubles where my code is only displaying the first section I have inputed "Sphere" and is not letting me input any other values when I go to Debug.

The basis of the code is to have the user choose a selction, and be able to input values to find the surface areas and volumes of a shape. Below is my code. (Also I am new to this so if there are any pointers I would greatly appreciate it!)

**This is for an exam I have so just some input as to where I am going wrong would be great. I want to learn it not have the whole thing completed for me**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //Text
    cout << "\nHello there! This program will help   " << endl;
    cout << "\ncalulate the surface areas and the    " << endl;
    cout << "\nvolumes of the displayed shapes below." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " A: Sphere          " << endl;
    cout << " B: Cube            " << endl;
    cout << " C: Dodecahedron    " << endl;
    cout << " D: Cylinder        " << endl;
    cout << " E: Cone            " << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;

//Variables

    double Sphere = 0.0,
        Cube = 0.0,
        Dodecahedron = 0.0,
        Cylinder = 0.0,
        Cone = 0.0;


     float A = (Sphere),
         B = (Cube),
         C = (Dodecahedron),
         D = (Cylinder),
         E = (Cone);


    //Question
    enter code here
    cout << "Please select one of the following..." << endl;
    cin >> A;
    cin >> B;
    cin >> C;
    cin >> D;
    cin >> E;
    {
        //Sphere

        int SphereRadius = 0.0;

        double pi = 3.1415926535898;

        double SphereSA = (4 * pi * (SphereRadius * SphereRadius));

        double SphereV = ((int(4 / 3)) * (pi * (SphereRadius * SphereRadius * SphereRadius)));

        if (Sphere);

        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need a radius.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the radius: " << endl;
        cin >> SphereRadius;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nWith the given radius... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << SphereSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << SphereRadius << endl;

    }
    {
        //Cube

        int CubeSide = 0.0;

        double CubeSA = (6 * (CubeSide * CubeSide));

        double CubeV = (CubeSide * CubeSide * CubeSide);

        if (Cube);

        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need a side length.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the side length: " << endl;
        cin >> CubeSide;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nWith the given side length... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << CubeSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << CubeV << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }
    {
        //Cone

        int ConeH = 0.0;

        double ConeR = 0.0;

        double ConeSA = (pi * ConeR * (ConeR + sqrt((ConeH * ConeH) + (ConeR * ConeR))));

        double ConeV = (pi * ((ConeR * ConeR) * (ConeH / 3)));

        if (Cone);

        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need a radius and a height.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the radius: " << endl;
        cin >> ConeR;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the height: " << endl;
        cin >> ConeH;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nWith the given side length... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << ConeSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << ConeV << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }
    {
        //Dodecahedron 

        int DodeEdge = 0.0;

        double DodeSA = (3 * (sqrt(25 + 10 * sqrt(5) * DodeEdge)));

        double DodeV = (DodeEdge * ((15 + (7 * sqrt(5)) / 4)));

        if (Dodecahedron);

        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need to have an edge.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the edge: " << endl;
        cin >> DodeEdge;
        string DodeEdge;

        cout << "\nWith the given edge length... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << DodeSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << DodeV << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }
    {
        //Cylinder

        int CylinderH = 0.0;

        int CylinderR = 0.0;

        double CylinderSA = ((2 * CylinderR * pi * CylinderH) + (2 * pi * (CylinderR * CylinderR)));

        double CylinderV = (pi * (CylinderR * CylinderR) * CylinderH);

        if (Cylinder);

        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need to have a radius and a height.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the radius: " << endl;
        cin >> CylinderR;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the height: " << endl;
        cin >> CylinderH;
        cout << endl;


        cout << "\nWith the given radius and height... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << CylinderSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << CylinderV << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }


    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you going from a high precision type of `double` to a lower precision type of `float`?  If you use `double`, you should use it everywhere unless there are functions that take `float`.

Comment: `if (Sphere);` and `if (Cube);`  and `if (Cone);` are pointless lines of code which do nothing. What did you mean by this?

Comment: `cin >> A;
    cin >> B;
    cin >> C;
    cin >> D;
    cin >> E;` is asking for 5 floats. You must type each hitting enter between. This is not the way to pick one type.

Comment: You need to have a *selection* or *choice* variable that is a `char` or `std::string`.  If you use `char`, you can use the variable in a `switch/case` statement to process the User's selection.

Comment: I am still trying to fully grasp how the float works @ThomasMatthewsTomas so I just did some quick reading through our textbook to figure it out and how to use it.

I was attempted to use if statements to see if it would help since I am very debunked as of right now.

Comment: My other big issue is that whenever i go to run the code it is only prompting the first sphere equation. But will not let me change any of the variables and comes out to zero each time, even when I select an of the other options

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the code order is not correct:

```
 int SphereRadius = 0.0;

        double pi = 3.1415926535898;

        double SphereSA = (4 * pi * (SphereRadius * SphereRadius));

        double SphereV = ((int(4 / 3)) * (pi * (SphereRadius * SphereRadius * SphereRadius)));
     cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the radius: " << endl;
        cin >> SphereRadius;
```

I modified code by using switch-case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

#define Sphere 1
#define Cube 2
#define Dodecahedron 3
#define Cylinder 4
#define Cone 5


using namespace std;

double pi = 3.1415926535898;

int main()
{
    //Text
    cout << "\nHello there! This program will help   " << endl;
    cout << "\ncalulate the surface areas and the    " << endl;
    cout << "\nvolumes of the displayed shapes below." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << " 1: Sphere          " << endl;
    cout << " 2: Cube            " << endl;
    cout << " 3: Dodecahedron    " << endl;
    cout << " 4: Cylinder        " << endl;
    cout << " 5: Cone            " << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please select one of the following..." << endl;

    //Variables

    int UserSelect = 0;
    cin >> UserSelect;

    while (UserSelect < 1 || UserSelect>5)
    {
        cout << "Please select the right option" << endl;
        cin >> UserSelect;
        cout << endl;
    }

    switch (UserSelect)
    {
    case  Sphere:
    {
        //Sphere

        int SphereRadius = 0.0;
        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need a radius.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the radius: " << endl;
        cin >> SphereRadius;
        cout << endl;
        double SphereSA = (4 * pi * (SphereRadius * SphereRadius));

        double SphereV = ((int(4 / 3)) * (pi * (SphereRadius * SphereRadius * SphereRadius)));

        cout << "\nWith the given radius... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << SphereSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << SphereRadius << endl;

    }
    break;
    case  Cube:
    {
        //Cube

        int CubeSide = 0.0;
        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need a side length.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the side length: " << endl;
        cin >> CubeSide;
        cout << endl;

        double CubeSA = (6 * (CubeSide * CubeSide));

        double CubeV = (CubeSide * CubeSide * CubeSide);

        cout << "\nWith the given side length... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << CubeSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << CubeV << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }
    break;
    case  Dodecahedron:

    {
        //Dodecahedron 

        int DodeEdge = 0.0;
        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need to have an edge.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the edge: " << endl;
        cin >> DodeEdge;

        double DodeSA = (3 * (sqrt(25 + 10 * sqrt(5) * DodeEdge)));

        double DodeV = (DodeEdge * ((15 + (7 * sqrt(5)) / 4)));


        //string DodeEdge;

        cout << "\nWith the given edge length... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << DodeSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << DodeV << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }

    break;
    case  Cylinder:
    {
        //Cylinder

        int CylinderH = 0.0;

        int CylinderR = 0.0;

        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need to have a radius and a height.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the radius: " << endl;
        cin >> CylinderR;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the height: " << endl;
        cin >> CylinderH;
        cout << endl;

        double CylinderSA = ((2 * CylinderR * pi * CylinderH) + (2 * pi * (CylinderR * CylinderR)));

        double CylinderV = (pi * (CylinderR * CylinderR) * CylinderH);


        cout << "\nWith the given radius and height... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << CylinderSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << CylinderV << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }
    break;
    case  Cone:
    {
        //Cone

        int ConeH = 0.0;

        double ConeR = 0.0;


        cout << "\nIn order to find the surface area and " << endl;
        cout << "\nvolume we will need a radius and a height.         " << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the radius: " << endl;
        cin >> ConeR;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nPlease input a positive number for the height: " << endl;
        cin >> ConeH;
        cout << endl;

        double ConeSA = (pi * ConeR * (ConeR + sqrt((ConeH * ConeH) + (ConeR * ConeR))));

        double ConeV = (pi * ((ConeR * ConeR) * (ConeH / 3)));


        cout << "\nWith the given side length... " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nSurface area will be: " << setprecision(2) << ConeSA << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\nVolume will be: " << setprecision(2) << ConeV << endl;
        cout << endl;

    }
    break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    

    return 0;
}
```